# flannel restart very often

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, kube-apiserver

Flannel on node restarts always.

Log as follows:

```
root@debian:~# docker logs faa668852544
I0425 07:14:37.721766       1 main.go:514] Determining IP address of default interface
I0425 07:14:37.724855       1 main.go:527] Using interface with name eth0 and address 192.168.50.19
I0425 07:14:37.815135       1 main.go:544] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.50.19)
E0425 07:15:07.825910       1 main.go:241] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-arm-bg9rn': Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-arm-bg9rn: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

master configuration:
`ubuntu: 16.04`

node:

```
embedded system with debian rootfs(linux4.9).
kubernetes version:v1.14.1
docker version：18.09
flannel version：v0.11.0
```

I hope flannel run normal on node.

Comment: can you share output of the `kubectl cluster-info --v=9` command

Answer (score 1):

First, for flannel to work correctly, you must pass `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` to kubeadm init.

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Set `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` to **1** by running

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```

Next is to create the clusterrole and clusterrolebinding

as follows:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```